# The element relation

Tags: set-theory

I am studying set theory and I have the following question: 
Are all the mathematical objects which we can quantify over, in essence, sets?
I ask you this also because I wish to know if, when we say that an object is an element of a set, that object is also set.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: In set theory, which is where most common advanced mathematics is founded upon, ALL objects are sets, even the "numbers" and "operations."

Comment: Thats the idea I have, although I sometimes ask myself because I get confused when people talk about elements and say that a set could have as elements sets, or other things.

Comment: If a set is a mathematical object which is a collection of mathematical objects, then of course that its elements can be themselves sets.

Comment: That being said, the fact that an element is also defined as a set itself is usually irrelevant.  The naive interpretation where you treat certain objects as simply elements and not sets themselves is often "good enough," for example when talking about the set $\{1,2\}$ you could talk about how $2$ is "*just a number*" or you could talk about how $2$ could be interpreted as a natural number and rigorously defined as the set $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$, or how $2$ could be interpreted as a rational number and defined as the infinite set which describes the rational number $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Will already said, in set theory every object we consider is a set.

- Every element of every set is a set,
- every natural number (in a precise way) is a set, e.g. $0 = \emptyset, 1 = \{ \emptyset \}, 2 = \{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \}$,
- every field, every vector space, every function, every topological space ... is a set,
- even every formula is a set.

The remarkable thing about set theory (though not at all a coincidence, it's been designed with precisely this intention) is that this theory is able to capture a great deal of mathematical concepts in a way that once all is said and done set theorists and mathematicians who don't think about a given mathematical concept as a set agree about its properties/theorems.

Comment: By formula, do you mean a predicate?

Comment: @Daàvid No, but predicates would be sets, too. What I mean is a formula like $\forall x \forall y \exists z \colon x \in z \wedge y \in z$. This formula 'in the meta theory' can be considered as a set in the 'set theory'. Much like natural numbers 'in the meta theory' can be considered as sets in the 'set theory'.

Comment: So, in the meta theory, it was made so that basically every concept os basically a set?

Comment: @Daàvid Historically, it was the other way around. Mathematics existed long before any kind of axiomatic set theory. And axiomatic set theory was designed so that it would encapsulate all of mathematics. To this day no one has come up with a mathematical concept that couldn't be captured by some form of axiomatic set theory and for the vast majority of concepts, the "mainstream set theory" $\mathrm{ZFC}$ is far more than enough to do that.

Comment: Yes, that i am aware of. But i had no idea things had been turned around that way by now

Comment: @Daàvid Most mathematicians aren't concerned with set theory, so I don't think things have been turned around.

Comment: Yes, i understand. Thank you